# Outputting an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array in JavaScript which is used to create a list of fixtures for teams to play against each other.

`[["a", "b", "c", "d"], ["a", "c", "b", "d"], ["a", "d", "b", "c"]]`

My current code:

```
var f = "";     
   for (var z=0; z<matches.length; z++)
   {
     f += "Fixture " + (z + 1 ) + " " + matches[z] + "<br/>";
   }  
  document.getElementById("ln").innerHTML = f;
}
```

this outputs the array as:

```
Fixture 1 a,b,c,d
Fixture 2 a,c,b,d
Fixture 3 a,d,b,c
```

However I would like it to look like:

```
Fixture 1
a V b
c V d
Fixture 2
a V c
b V d
```

Basically I need to add a 'V' every second value after the first, and add an additional < br/ > after every 2 values.

Could someone help me out with this or point me in the right direction, please?

Comment: What seems to be a problem? Have you learned nested loops yet?

Comment: You can add one more loop for doing this.

Comment: I understand what nested loops are, however, I'm not too familiar with arrays like this. In this case, matches[z], the [z] can refer to ["a", "b", "c", "d"], however I'm not too sure how I can refer to just the team 'a', for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

spycbanda's code is good, but only works for four teams. By using an inner loop, you can handle an indefinite number of teams:

```
var f="";
for(var z=0; z<matches.length; z++) {
  f += "Fixture " + (z + 1) + "<br/>";
  for(let y=0; y<matches[z].length; y+=2)
    f+= matches[z][y] + " V " + matches[z][y+1] + "<br/>";
  f += "<br/>";   
}
document.getElementById("ln").innerHTML = f;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's perfect!

Answer (score 3):

Try this. Upvote me if it works.

```
var f = "";     
   for (var z=0; z<matches.length; z++)
   {
     code1 = matches[z].slice(0,2).join(" V ");
     code2 = matches[z].slice(2).join(" V ");
     f += "Fixture " + (z + 1 ) + "<br/>" + code1 + "<br/>" + code2 + "<br/>";
   }  
  document.getElementById("ln").innerHTML = f;
}
```

Comment: I guess you didn't get upvoted because you asked for it, nice solution btw.

Comment: No issue. I am happy helping you.

Comment: Sorry, I did upvote but I don't have the reputation for it to show. I do appreciate the answer though!